# C# post-filter a message? Trying to get the active control after the click has been processed

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently working on a C# message filter that logs info about the Winform app on every click. However I'm having trouble because oftentimes the click action itself triggers a change in the information I'm trying to log. More specifically, I'm trying to get info about the active control using PreFilterMessage, but if the click changes which control is active the logged results will all be for the previous control and not the current one.

Is there a "PostFilterMessage", or a way to execute the click and *then* run the function? Is there a better implementation? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't think so. Well, there's the `WH_CALLWNDPROCRET` hook, but you cannot install one of these in managed code, so it can't be done from C#. You'll need to write the hook DLL in C or C++. But I'm suspect of your design. This seems like an X-Y problem. Why do you need to know the active control *after* the click has been processed? The message is sent to the button, and the button is the control that processed the event, so getting that button in the pre-filter is *correct*. State that changes *after* the click message/event has been received is not something your log should be concerned with.

Comment: Yes you're right, I have no problem processing buttons, but it becomes a problem when I change tabs in a dock or when dealing with a MDIclient. ActivePanel/ActiveMDIChild/FocusedView etc all return the previous one and not the one that was just clicked.